# How to add Disqus to comment section on Page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, comments, disqus

I have Wordpress site and I have incorporated Disqus into my posts but I am not sure how to add them to my pages.

any help appreciated

Comment: Help us help you, especially if you can show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if your theme allow you to add comments section to your Pages.If yes then do, otherway 
 
Find `wp-content/comments.php` file 
Go to `wp-content/pages.php` 

 Then `Include("comments.php")`at suitable position.

UPDATE and there you go.